# jQuery UI dialog in jQuery submit() event (am I doing it right?)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, submit, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm making a form which on submitting checks if the user_name input field is filled. And if it is then prompts a **jQuery UI** dialog box. If "Yes" is pressed then the answer is sent to a variable *userOKWithIt* which is then used with second call to the **submit()** function.

I'm doing this because I don't want the user to be able to submit the form with empty user_name using the Firebug console for example (writing (**'form).submit()** in it).

Is this the right way to do it? I have the feeling that I'm missing something essential. I don't like the idea of a global variable which stores user's answer.
Here's the code:

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
.html('<p>Are you sure you want to continue?</p>')
.dialog({
autoOpen: false,
resizable: false,
title: 'Continue anyway?',
buttons: {
    "Yes": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        userOkWithIt = true;
        $('form').submit();
    },
    No: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
}
});

var userOkWithIt = false;
$('form').submit(function(){    
if(!$('input[name="user_name"]').val()){
    //Don't submit because there is no user name written
    return false;
}else{
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    if(userOkWithIt){
        return true;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: The user will probably be able to submit the form if they disable JavaScript. Or, they could just unbind the `submit` event you've bound. If they're savvy enough to want to do it, they'll be able to.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker It's not a practice to "protect" submits with JavaScript, am I understanding this right?

Comment: You can definitely do it, but just remember it can always be subverted. Make sure your server does the important validation too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly a bit confused about your goal; you really need to decide how much you want to protect against the educated js-programmer who wants to submit your form in a way other than you want him to.

---

EDIT: Also, you should look into HTML5 Required Inputs: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_required.asp

**Probably the best idea** (that I can think of) is to unbind your submit event when the user says yes.  That way, the form will submit without any global boolean.  It would also allow you to simplify your submit event handler to ask the user for confirmation, and then return false.

Now, if you **just want to get the userOkWithIt variable out of global scope**, you could use closure to accomplish that.

Here is some untested example code.  The >>> <<< indicates where I made important changes.

```
>>> var yesFunction; <<<

var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('<p>Are you sure you want to continue?</p>')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Continue anyway?',
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                >>> yesFunction(); <<<

                $('form').submit();
            },
            No: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });

>>> function() {                   <<<
>>> var userOkWithIt = false;      <<<

$('form').submit(function() {

    >>> yesFunction = function() { <<<
    >>>     userOkWithIt = true;   <<<
    >>> }                          <<<

    if(!$('input[name="user_name"]').val()) {
        //Don't submit because there is no user name written
        return false;
    } else {
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        if(userOkWithIt) {
            return true;
        }
    }
});

>>> }();                           <<<
```

Hope it helped.  Let me know if you would like any clarification.  I will try to come back in the next few days.

Comment: So in jQuery, no one is trying to "protect" their submits (if we're not counting PHP Validation)?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Could you please restate it?

Comment: I meant that, as far as I understand, the validation using jQuery is not as important as the server-side validation, right?

Comment: Correct.  I don't care what js you write; if I want to submit the form, I'm going to.  Server-side validation is for security, etc.  Client-side validation is for a pretty ui and user convenience.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a link to HTML5 Required Inputs.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yeah, the HTML5 Required input is good, but only if it's used with a server-side validation as you said, because it's even more easy to be avoided.